# Best way to propagate all arguments to python script to a function

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, argparse

I have a python script `script_A` and in its `main`, it calls another python function in a different file.

`script_A` will be called like below:

```
script_A --option1 "foo" --option2 "hoo"
```

Inside `script_A` I have:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   # call another function `func_B` defined in a different file
```

I want to pass all the arguments passed to `script_A` in `func_B` without actually parsing the arguments.

i.e. I'd like to use `argparse` inside `func_B`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `argparse` parses `sys.argv` by default.  That is available from anywhere in your calling stack.  Just `import sys` to examine it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use built-in module [sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) to get argument list. Then do things you wanna.

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that, as soon as your script is run, you're gonna get your arguments in a list (`sys.argv`) split by whitespace (where the first item is the script's name), so you're not going to be getting the initial string "per se".

With this in mind, however, you could do something like this:

Have the `__main__` in a file like this:

*mod1.py*:

```
import sys
from mod2 import foo


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo(sys.argv[1:]) # To remove the script's name, which is always the first argument
```

And then run the argparser in another module (which in this example I called `mod2.py`) like this:

*mod2.py*:

```
import argparse


def make_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some foos.')
    parser.add_argument('--foo', type=str, nargs='+', help='a foo',)
    parser.add_argument('--baz', type=str, help='a baz')
    return parser


def foo(args):
    parser = make_parser()
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args(args)
    print "Got me some foos: %s" % (parsed_args.foo)
    print "And a baz: %s" % (parsed_args.baz)
```

Running `$ python ./mod1.py --foo bar1 bar2 --baz 1` would result in:

```
$ python ./mod1.py --foo bar1 bar2 --baz 1
Got me some foos: ['bar1', 'bar2']
And a baz: 1
```

Comment: Is sys.argv[1:] always valid?
Is it possible that it throws an exception (if there is no arguments)?

I tried with no arguments and it was fine, but wanted to make sure.

Comment: As long as you call it from the command line, yeah. Even if you don't pass any arguments, there will always be one (the script's name). You can try yourself: Add a `    print sys.argv` in the line before the call to `foo(sys.argv[1:])` (or right after the `if __name__ == "__main__":`) and play a little **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use `argparse` in `func_B` exactly the way you would have used it from `script_A`. It'll work fine. Command-line arguments and command-line argument parsing tools like `argparse` don't care what file you're in.